# maven error cannot find symbol method encodeBase64String

Tags: java, apache, maven, jakarta-ee, pom.xml

when I'm trying to do `mvn install` in eclipse, I'm getting below error:

```
ERROR] /C:/myproj/package/MyClass.java:[43,49] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method encodeBase64String(byte[])
```

I even kepted below dependency, BUT still showing that error.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
    <version>20041127.091804</version>
</dependency>
```

Please suggest me what could be wrong and what I've to do?

**PROBLEM RESOLVED:**

```
Just changed version to 1.4 and it got worked!
```

Comment: Showing your code would help, esp. the imports & the method call

Comment: Maybe duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20703573/base64-encodebase64string-not-found

Comment: @Reimeus Iam getting above error when iam running maven, so what you check in java code?

Comment: @Reimeus please check i edited above

Comment: Have you checked the Base64 class in the commons-codec library version 20041127.091804 and made sure the method `encodeBase64String` is avaialble in that version?

Answer (score 0):

Did you do `import` on the class `Base64` or `import static`? Your usage suggests you did the former. If that be the case, then you need to use `Base64.encodeBase64String` instead of just calling `encodeBase64String`

Comment: I edited my post, please check it.. here is what I used:  String base64BodyString = Base64.encodeBase64String("<div>ASDF</div>".getBytes());